# php insert date into a datetime column in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a table with a `datetime` column in SQL Server. I searched here, but found no solution. I only found how to insert datetime into a datetime column in SQL Server. I need to save a  `<input type="date" value="2023-06-28">` into datetime column in SQL Server, but no need with hours, minutes and seconds. But how to do it?

I get:

> "Bei der Konvertierung eines nvarchar-Datentyps in einen
> datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs"

My php/query in PHP is:

```
 .... nullif('".$date."', ''), ........
```

Comment: [sidenote] In Mysql, there is a type of data known as date (not datetime) . The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. For details , see [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATE,%3Amm%3Ass%20'%20format.)

Comment: yes, i know. but i use sql server and have an existing table with datetime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date to be entered into the database without the current time, but rather just set to yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000 then this is how I do it:

```
$DOB = htmlspecialchars(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(<input>));
```

This converts the input into the correct format for  SQL Server, but sets the time to 00:00:00.000, just replace `<input>` with the correct reference to your input field.

Other than that, there is no way, (that i'm aware of), to remove a the actual time component of a DateTime column in SQL Server.

Comment: i get the same error :-/

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL Insert statement.

Comment: $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (datetime_column) VALUES (nullif('".$date."', '')");
$insert->execute();

Comment: my update query works i take GETDATE()

Comment: $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (datetime_column) VALUES (nullif('".$date."', '')"););
$insert->execute();
You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your values to accommodate for the prepare statement. You should also bind your parameters instead of including them in your insert statement, to help prevent against SQL Injection.